# German Market: How can I only show the imprint in the footer of the mail?

Tags: plugins

Currently I'm looking for a way to modify the code of the Plugin WooCommerce-German-Market.

The goal is to change the email footer so only imprint is shown (not the full terms etc.)

My first hint was to modify a code for removing special tags. But it's not working.

My custom function.php

```
function showOnlyImprint(){
          
        $imprint_page_id = get_option( WGM_Helper::get_wgm_option( 'impressum' ) );
        $imprint_page = get_post( $imprint_page_id );
        
        WGM_Email::the_mail_footer_section(
                __( 'Legal Information', 'woocommerce-german-market' ),
                 $imprint_page->post_content
            );
      
}                                                      

add_filter('get_email_de_footer','showOnlyImprint');
```

But I'm pretty sure that `get_email_de_footer` is wrong.

In the file `WooCommerce-German-Market.php` I read the line:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer',                                 array( 'WGM_Email', 'disable_footer_text_for_admin_emails' ) );
```

But I'm confused, what is the array doing? I cannot find `WGM_Email`? Is it a file?

> Updated: WGM_Email is a prefix for the `WGM_Email.php`. Good to know. But still it's not working

Comment: If you are interested, I found the basic code here: https://kriesi.at/support/topic/e-mails-german-market/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after digging around and trying to understand the syntax of wordpress's API, I found the solution:

```
add_filter('wgm_email_display_terms', false);
add_filter('wgm_email_display_cancellation_policy', false);
add_filter('wgm_email_display_gerneral_customer_information_headline', false);
add_filter('wgm_email_display_delivery', false);
add_filter('wgm_email_display_payment_methods', false);
```

I hope this helps you!